# HMASTER fails to run in psedo distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed hadoop 1.2.0 on Ubuntu.. All the services namenode, sec namenode, datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker running well.

I then installed hbase-0-94.8 and I hope, configurations are okay as well. But HMaster fails to start on port 9000.. It actually starts and then drops down.

I have self ssh on. It is working

my /etc/hosts entires,

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost prakashl 

    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

kandabap@prakashl:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/conf$ jps
2735 HQuorumPeer
3017 HRegionServer
2270 TaskTracker
3715 Jps
2100 JobTracker
1845 DataNode
2009 SecondaryNameNode
1688 NameNode
```

hbase-master.log

> > > > >
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:37,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ActiveMasterManager: Master=localhost,60000,1400023716583
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:38,108 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:39,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:40,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:41,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:42,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:43,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:44,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:45,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:46,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
> > > >         2014-05-14 09:28:47,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 
> > > >         <<<<<

I copied jar files from hadoop folders to hbase/lib folder to address incompatibilities if any.

```
kandabap@prakashl:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/logs$ netstat -ntla

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48575           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58304           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47238         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42987           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50030           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60020         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35255           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Could you please show me your hbase-site.xml??

Comment: <configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/zookeeper</value>
</property>

</configuration>

Comment: Looks ok. Is your NN running at 9000??

Comment: Nope it runs at 8020...
NameNode 'localhost:8020'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of **hbase.rootdir** from **hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase** to **hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase** in **hbase-site.xml**, and restart HBase.

Comment: Perfect. I completely missed noticing it. Thanks bunch.